# Geometric intuition/picture behind tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

I am looking for a way to understand tensor product spaces intuitively. I understand both the basis-dependent and the algebraic basis-free definitions. What I am struggling with is interpreting what something of the form
$$v \otimes w, \quad v \in V, w \in W$$
means geometrically, where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces.

For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is very easy to explain and visualize what any vector or basis looks like. For an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ we can decompose it into
$$x = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3e_3$$
and this geometrically makes clear sense, we are simply breaking down the vector into its component parts. In other words, if $x$ denotes the position of some particle we can say it is $a_i$ distance in the $i$th direction ($e_i)$.

However, in the case of tensor products, does a similar geometric interpretation hold? How does one exactly interpret an arbitrary vector $v \otimes w$? To make the question simpler, take $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ (with basis $\{e_i^1\}$) and $W = \mathbb{R}^3$ (with basis $\{e_i^2\})$. Then
$$\begin{align}v \otimes w = &a_1 e^1_1\otimes e_1^2 + a_2 e^1_2\otimes e_1^2 + a_3 e^1_1\otimes e_2^2 + \\&a_4 e^1_2\otimes e_2^2 + a_5 e^1_1\otimes e_3^2 + a_6 e^1_2\otimes e_3^2 \end{align}$$

The only picture I am able to have in mind is in the context of quantum mechanics. If the two vector spaces represent different observable quantities, then I interpret the tensor product as taking into account two things at once. But this is unsatisfying to me in the general mathematical setting, especially geometrically. Does such an interpretation even exist?

Comment: By the looks of your basis, it seems you want $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $W = \mathbb{R}^3$ . A simple way to get an intuition of the tensor product is to take it  an operation that takes two vectors (of dimensions $m$, $n$), and returns a  matrix (of dimension $(m,n)$) 
https://media.cheggcdn.com/study/edd/edd9eb63-43c6-468a-8a9d-7f859ec21c79/DC-1776V9.png

Comment: @user3257842 Yes that was a typo, I have updated the post. Thanks! That is a nice example, I assume it's meant to show the isomorphism between matrices and tensor products.

Comment: An area is the tensor product of two lengths...

Comment: To be exact, the illustrated operation, that takes an $n$-dimensional column vector  and an $m$-dimensional row vector to return an $n*m$-dimensional matrix, can be interpeted as the bilinear map associated to a tensor product.

Comment: One way to start getting more geometrical intuition for tensor products is by studying *mixed* tensor algebra $\bigotimes(E^*,E)$ where $E,E^*$ are dual spaces, in which balanced mixed tensors are used to describe geometric quantities (i.e. quantities invariant under change of basis).

Comment: I do not want to sound mysterious, so I would like to mention that I was talking about the tensor product of positive spaces, not the tensor product of vector spaces (the definition is analogous though).